# create record with one field but that field should be read only while doing edit

Tags: page-layout, read-only

I want to create the record with one field but that field should be read only in edit mode (using default create and edit layout only). I just want to show that the field read-only on the page layout while editing. is that possible?

Let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can create validation rule to prevent edit for name field. Like below - 

AND(NOT(ISNEW()) , ISCHANGED(Name))

this will throw error and will not allow to edit name.
```

Comment: yes thats one option we can do that. but i dont think we can make readonly right?

Answer (score 0):

You can make fields read only in the profile settings, or through field accessibility. This allows you to make the field read only for certain profiles. For example you might make it read only for all profiles except the system admin.

Comment: field is category name, users can create category but while edit category name should not be editable. and create permission is for all user. just want to restrict edit

Comment: Two things I can think of would be to create a vf page for this and then you have much better control over the fields or you could create a validation to stop the field being changed. ISCHANGED(fieldname__c)